# I am trying to use "google_mobile_ads" in my flutter project but I am getting this migrated to the Android embedding v2

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

The plugin `google_mobile_ads` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.

*So I tried following the steps but I couldn't found the  "MainActivity.java" in my project anyWhere and couldn't follow along*

[MyProject tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB23S.png)

[migration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lSCd.png)

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration
this the Link Which it is suggesting to follow

Comment: Below link might useful for you
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Comment: i tried couldn't Follow it along

Comment: MainActivity.java / kt located in "android/kotlin" folder not "lib" folder.

Comment: I had seen it could not find it, look at the image uploaded As MyProject Tree

Comment: you can find out MainActivity.kt in the Kotlin folder because by default flutter creates the android native side in Kotlin unless you specified while creating the project.

Comment: Thank you soo much, this was my mistake I was Editing the meta-data instead of added the meta-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just open this files in your project and copy >> paste this lines of code and it will work .......make sure to delete all lines of code in your this files and replace it to this new ones.

1: MainActivity.java

---

```
package co.appbrewery.flash_chat;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  
}
```

---

2: styles.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

---

3: AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
          package="co.appbrewery.flash_chat">  
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application android:label="flash_chat" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
              until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
              there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
              defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

---